# Sort digits of a number in ascending or descending order in Excel 2010?

Tags: excel, vba

I am Using Excel 2010. i write any number(say 69138) in cell A1. I want to display this number in both ascending order (13689) and descending order (98631) in cells B1 and C1, respectively.(2) what will be the VBA CODE, behind a command button for this same purpose.Thanks in anticipation

Answer (score 3):

You can type this in the cell B1 to display A1 in ascending order:
`=TEXT(SUM(SMALL(--MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),1),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))))*10^(LEN(A1)-ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))))),REPT("0",LEN(A1)))`
the press ** Ctrl + Shift + Enter**
For descending order type in the cell C1:
`=TEXT(SUM(LARGE(--MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),1),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))))*10^(LEN(A1)-ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))))),REPT("0",LEN(A1))).`

Also you can write a user defined function like this :
1- Hold down the **ALT + F11** keys, and it opens the **Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications window**.
2- Click **Insert > Module**, and paste the following code in the Module **Window**.

```
Function SortNumsInCell(pNum As String, Optional pOrder As Boolean) As String
'Update 20140717
Dim xOutput As String
For i = 0 To 9
  For j = 1 To UBound(VBA.Split(pNum, i))
    xOutput = IIf(pOrder, i & xOutput, xOutput & i)
  Next
Next
SortNumsInCell = xOutput
End Function
```

3-Then save and close this code, go back to your worksheet, and enter this formula **=sortnumsincell(A1)** into a blank cell next to your data
**Note:** If you want to sort the numbers in descending order, please enter this formula =sortnumsincell(A1,1).

Comment: I am grateful to you for ur kind help,Many many thanks.